# change text on h2 for contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am making a website with one contact form but the same contact form has 2 links, the question is how to change the `h2` tag on the contact form.
I have found how to change it works great but I want this code to work only on one link exp. here is the code

```
document.getElementById("h2id").innerHTML = "new text";

<a href="#" id="link1">link1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">link2</a>
```

when I click on the link2 I want the contact form h2 to be changed on new text but only on the link2

the default text on the contact form
    OneText
and the changed text when I click on the second link.
    New Text

Comment: check this sample https://jsfiddle.net/o17msnd9/

Comment: Doesn't seems you have shown any effort or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a click event handler by setting **[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick)** attribute

```js
function change(ele) {
  document.getElementById("h2id").innerHTML = ele.id == 'link2' ? "new text" : "old text";
  // updating content based on clicked element id
}
```

```html
<h2 id="h2id">old text</h2>

<a href="#" id="link1" onclick="change(this)">link1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" onclick="change(this)">link2</a>
```

or using jQuery use **[`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** event handler

```js
$('#link2,#link1').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // prevent default click event action
  $('#h2id').text(this.id == 'link2' ? "new text" : "old text");
  // change h2 text based on clicked element id
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="h2id">old text</h2>

<a href="#" id="link1">link1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">link2</a>
```

Comment: because its a popup when I cancel the second link and click on the first it keeps the changed text, what should I do then

Comment: same result, link1 keeps like link2 if link2 is clicked before link1

Comment: @DroDro i couldn't get you

Comment: Its so slimple :) sorry for the bad english.
When I click on the second link the text is changed (thats great) but when i go back and click on the first link, it keeps the changed text not the default one.

Comment: @DroDro : updated the answer.... when you clicked the first link, text will change to default

Comment: @Prabav C Bakan Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 id="h2id">My title</h2>

<a href="#" id="link1" onclick="changeH2Title()">link1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2" onclick="changeBack()">link2</a>

<script>

function changeH2Title() {
    document.getElementById("h2id").innerHTML = "new text";
}

function changeBack() {
    document.getElementById("h2id").innerHTML = "link1";
}

</script>
```

If you just want to use javascript, then i would use the "onclick" event.
Check out my example.

Comment: because its a popup when I cancel the second link and click on the first it keeps the changed text, what should I do then

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Its so slimple :) sorry for the bad english.
When I click on the second link the text is changed (thats great) but when i go back and click on the first link, it keeps the changed text not the default one.

Answer (score 0):

with pure javascript you can de like below

```js
    obj=document.getElementById("link2");
    obj.onclick=function(){
      change_txt(document.getElementById("h2id"),"new text");
    };

    obj=document.getElementById("link1");
    obj.onclick=function(){
      change_txt(document.getElementById("h2id"),"old text");
    };
                 
                 
                 
function change_txt(obj,txt){


obj.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="h2id">old text</h2>
    <a href="#" id="link1" >link1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link2">link2</a>
```

Comment: because its a popup when I cancel the second link and click on the first it keeps the changed text, what should I do then

Comment: @DroDro for thanks and improve site you can vote up correct answers